# How to time every request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a debug bar for Spring Boot similar to the one found in the Symfony framework that will display things like HTTP status, authentication details etc. I'm doing this using a postHandle interceptor, injecting the relevant data into the Model.

One of the things I would like to display is how long a request took. I've found a few tutorials for request timing but they all target one specific controller method.

Is there a way to time every single request and then inject the time into my Model?

Comment: Add the Actuator, and [Boot will time your requests automatically](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector).

Comment: Is there a way to take that data from Actuator and inject it into a Model?

Comment: Yes it's possible see here https://medium.com/@sonus21/monitoring-and-profiling-spring-boot-application-a35d7e7f9290